# My unordered_set elements change in a scope without modifying them

Tags: c++

I am trying to use an unordered_set to keep track of the uniqueness of some char* elements but in this scope the unordered_set modifies and elements even dissapear from it for no reason. I am displaying the elements at the beginning and before modifying it and it does display different elements and I cant get why.

```
for (unordered_set <char*> ::iterator it = unique_states.begin(); it != unique_states.end(); it++)
                cout << *it << " ";
            cout << endl;
            set <int> state;
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(states_names[it_states]); i++)
            {
                int index = states_names[it_states][i] - '0';
                for (set <int> ::iterator it = concatenations[index][j].begin(); it != concatenations[index][j].end(); it++)
                    state.insert(*it);
            }
            strcpy_s(temp, "");
            for (set <int> ::iterator it = state.begin(); it != state.end(); it++)
            {
                char aux[2];
                aux[0] = *it + '0';
                aux[1] = '\0';
                strcat_s(temp, aux);
            }
            int position = 0;
            for (unordered_set <char*> ::iterator it = unique_states.begin(); it != unique_states.end(); it++)
                cout << *it << " ";
            cout << endl;
            for (unordered_set <char*> ::iterator it = unique_states.begin(); it != unique_states.end(); it++)
            {
                cout << *it << " ";
                /*if (strcmp(*it, temp) == 0)
                    break;*/
                position++;
            }
            if (unique_states.count(temp) == 0)
                position = it_states + 1;
            cout << "Position : " << position << endl;
            dfa_transitions[it_states].push_back(make_pair(j + 'a', position));
            unique_states.insert(temp);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess here is that the problems stems from you using pointers as key in your set.

When you use pointers as keys in a set or a map, it is the ***pointer itself*** that is the key, not whatever data they point to. That means two strings (assuming your `char*` points to null-terminated byte strings) that might compare equal with `strcmp` might not be equal if they are stored in different locations.

If you want to use strings for keys in your maps or sets, use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting inside the `unordered_set` while iterating over it. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert and specifically:

> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated.